# What were the reasons for the Federal Art Project?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, economy, 1930s, 1940s

From August 29, 1935, until June 30, 1943 United States promote what they called Federal Art Project.

> Reputed to have created more than 200,000 separate works, FAP artists
>   created posters, murals and paintings. Some works still stand among
>   the most-significant pieces of public art in the country.[Wiki]

I think this is one of the most interesting  maneuvers of the New Deal it seems such forward-looking and philanthropic. I wonder what were the best benefits that they supposed they would have by this maneuver.

Comment: The primary goal was to spend money.  The US economy was in a depression, and the government was deploying economic stimulus along all fronts.

Comment: Same benefits as digging a hole in a road and filling it back, but (on some occasions) prettier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See PBS.org's website for supporting material about their show *American Experience* for the episode: [The Works Progress Administration (WPA)](http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/americanexperience/features/general-article/dustbowl-wpa/).

> Under the direction of Harry Hopkins, an enthusiastic ex-social worker
> who had come from modest means, the WPA would spend more than $11
> million in employment relief before it was canceled in 1943. The work
> relief program was more expensive than direct relief payments, but
> worth the added cost, Hopkins believed. “Give a man a dole,” he
> observed, “and you save his body and destroy his spirit. Give him a
> job and you save both body and spirit”.

The article answers the question 'why support art?':

> When federal support of artists was questioned, Hopkins answered,
> “Hell! They’ve got to eat just like other people.” The WPA supported
> tens of thousands of artists, by funding creation of 2,566 murals and
> 17,744 pieces of sculpture that decorate public buildings nationwide.
> The federal art, theater, music, and writing programs, while not
> changing American culture as much as their adherents had hoped, did
> bring more art to more Americans than ever before or since. The WPA
> program in the arts led to the creation of the National Foundation for
> the Arts and the National Endowment for the Humanities.

For primary source material at the National Archives, see NARA's entry page,
[Records of the Work Projects Administration](http://archives.gov/research/guide-fed-records/groups/069.html#69.5.2).

Answer (score 1):

As you know, the Federal Art Project was a part of the WPA during the Great Depression. Quoting Wikipedia:

> The FAP's primary goals were to employ out-of-work artists and to provide art for non-federal government buildings: schools, hospitals, libraries, etc. The work was divided into art production, art instruction and art research. The primary output of the art-research group was the Index of American Design, a mammoth and comprehensive study of American material culture.
>   The FAP was one of a short-lived series of Depression-era visual-arts programs, which included the Section of Painting and Sculpture and the Public Works of Art Project (both of which, unlike the WPA-operated FAP, were operated by the U.S. Department of the Treasury).

Basically, we were in a depression, so we needed to spend money to stimulate the economy. It had the added benefits of keeping artists off the streets and giving public buildings nice decorations.